# Combine Text cell & ComboBox cell to a TreeView column GTK C#?

Tags: c#, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I need to create a treeview column which contains both a text cell & Combobox cell.

I want to use a text cell if the value is one. 
I want to use a Combobox cell if values are more than one.

Can you please share help link or sample on this.

Thanks!
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Created CellRenderComboBox object and Add this object to TreeviewColumn object.
The User need to register **cellRendererCombo.EditingStarted += CellEditingStartedHandler** event for updating combo box runtime.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
private Gtk.TreeView treeview1;
private int guiThreadId;
private bool stop = false;
private int threadId = 0;
public delegate void ThreadStart();


public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();

    guiThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

    // Create our TreeView
    treeview1 = new Gtk.TreeView();

    Gtk.ScrolledWindow scrolledWindow = new ScrolledWindow();
    scrolledWindow.Add(treeview1);

    Gtk.VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.Add(scrolledWindow);
    this.Add(vBox);

    CellRendererCombo cellRendererCombo = new CellRendererCombo();
    Gtk.TreeViewColumn treeViewColumn = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumn.Title = "TYPE";
    treeViewColumn.PackStart(cellRendererCombo, false);
    treeViewColumn.AddAttribute(cellRendererCombo, "text", 0);
    cellRendererCombo.Editable = true;
    cellRendererCombo.Model = new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string));
    cellRendererCombo.Mode = CellRendererMode.Editable;
    cellRendererCombo.TextColumn = 0;
    cellRendererCombo.HasEntry = false;
    cellRendererCombo.WidthChars = 20;
    cellRendererCombo.Style = Pango.Style.Normal;
    cellRendererCombo.Edited += OnActionChanged;
    cellRendererCombo.EditingStarted += CellEditingStartedHandler;

    treeview1.AppendColumn(treeViewColumn);

    Gtk.ListStore listStore = new ListStore(typeof(string));
    listStore.AppendValues("A");
    listStore.AppendValues("B");

}

protected void OnEdited(object sender, Gtk.EditedArgs args)
{
    Gtk.TreeSelection selection = treeview1.Selection;
    Gtk.TreeIter iter;
    selection.GetSelected(out iter);
    treeview1.Model.SetValue(iter, 1, args.NewText); // the CellRendererText
}

protected void CellEditingStartedHandler(object o, EditingStartedArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"CellEditingStartedHandler");
    if (o is Gtk.CellRendererCombo)
    {
        Gtk.CellRendererCombo cellRendererCombo = (Gtk.CellRendererCombo)o;

        ((Gtk.ListStore)cellRendererCombo.Model).Clear();
        ((Gtk.ListStore)cellRendererCombo.Model).AppendValues("A");
        ((Gtk.ListStore)cellRendererCombo.Model).AppendValues("B");
    }
}
}
```